# getting iframe content in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

So I have

```
$('.theiframe').load(function(){
   var content = $(this.contentDocument).find('pre').html();
}
```

and in FF, Chrome, IE 8,9 the content of the iframe is inserted into variable content properly....but then when I use IE7, content will instead become 'null'.

What should be done to properly get the iframe content and store it into a variable once the iframe is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the iframe a name and access it that way.

```
$(window.frames[ "iframename" ].document).find("pre").html();
```

Comment: FYI if selecting iframes by name is important to you, jQuery can handle it: `$('[name=iframename]')`. But there's nothing wrong with selecting an iframe by means other than its name — it certainly has no bearing on how to retrieve the internal document.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method can be used to access the document of an iframe. Your code becomes:

```
$('.theiframe').load(function(){
    var content = $(this).contents().find('pre').html();
}
```